# Sum hours and minutes in Google Sheet

Tags: date, google-sheets, time

I have in my sheet a value, for example 2,01. 
This value correspond to hh,mm and so 2 hours and 1 minute (in this case).
I would to sum all values with this format.
And so, for example, 2,01 + 0,59 = 3,00 (hours)

What is the formula?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JD3RR0d9D4hEzmQp8siOBjekxRfe_6PyC16MCDU1bBg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula highlighted in green (adding range `A:A`):

`=ArrayFormula((SUM(INT(A:A)))+(INT(SUM(MOD(A:A;1)/0,6)))+(MOD(SUM(MOD(A:A;1)/0,6);1)*60/100))`

Three segments are added:

1.) The `SUM` of the integer portions of the original numbers

2.) The integer portion of the `SUM` of the decimal portions of the original numbers `MOD` `0,6` (i.e., converted to a 60-seconds-per-whole system rather than a 100-parts-per-whole system)

3.) The `MOD` of the decimal portion of the previous segment, converted between the 60-second and 100-parts systems.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A; ","; ".")))); "[h].mm"))
```

[image]